# How to do retrieved from

Tags: apacite

I want to cite this paper but I don't know how since this is an online source. I don't know which command to use and how can I have urldate?

Burnside, C., Eichenbaum, M., & Rebelo, S. (2007): „Currency crisis models.” Retrieved from https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/rebelo/htm/currency%20crisis%20models%20Ed.pdf

Comment: If and how a url access date is shown is up to the bibliography style (and package) you use. Can you show us a short example document and the `.bib` entry for this reference so that we can be sure which style you use? (See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.) (The question is tagged `apacite` and the reference looks very APA-y, but I'd like to be sure to avoid sending you off on a wild goose chase.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of entries in [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=5094924455109924396&hl=fr&as_sdt=0,5&sciodt=0,5) associated to this ref.

However, the following seems to be the preferred one:

```
@article{burnside2008currency,
  title={Currency crises models},
  author={Burnside, Craig and Eichenbaum, Martin and Rebelo, Sergio},
  journal={The New Palgrave Dictionary of Economics: Volume 1--8},
  pages={1243--1246},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

It does not seem to be **only** an online document, but also a journal article.
You can add a note for the URL and accessed date :

```
publisher={Springer},
note={Accessed on 2019-11-05, \url{https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/66dc/07b6298a4fbc7a2a969226b00d43c324aaba.pdf}}
}
```

Warning 1: don't forget to add a coma after `{Springer}`,

Warning 2: the use of `\url` requires package `url`.

Finally, you can cite this article using the command `\cite{burnside2008currency}`.

**EDIT** full procedure to get bibtex from Google Scholar:

1. Go to Google Scholar and enter the name of the paper you are willing to cite.

   If no satisfying result, go to 2., otherwise, click on the quote symbol under the result (bottom left of the picture):
   [image]

   Then select BibTeX:
   [image]

   And copy paste the resulting text into you `bib` file:
   [image]
2. If you did not find the paper you were looking for, try to copy paste the abstract (or any other (long) part of the paper) into a search engine.

[image]

Clicking on the citations' number will bring you to the papers citing this research.

[image]
 Clicking on the name of the paper at the top of the page will bring you to the steps described in 1.

Note that there are plenty of softwares/add-ons to facilitate bibtex importation, such as [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) to name just one.

Comment: How did you get this? Is there any website to get bibtex from url - besides google scholar?

Comment: That is the point, I got this from [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), let me edit the answer as it won't fit in a comment...